# MobilePush Notification for Marketing Cloud Cordova plugn not displayed

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, cordova

We are using Marketing CLoud Cordova plugin (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) to implement MobilePush notification on the App but its not working when the Cordova plugin Firebasex is included in the dependency package.

It seems like the message sent from Marketing cloud is received on the Cordova Firebasex SDK as an alert with the messageType "Data". Due to that the message is not displayed on the mobile by default. If we try to send the same message directly using Firebase API, it will show the notification and message type is "Notification"

subtitle: "Feb 07 V002"

messageType: "data"

_h: "nuU1OPKKJgxvvfuF4tgVPQAAAAAA"

_m: "Mjk6MTE0OjA"

_r: "b7d2ef7c-a19d-4bf3-8e59-270e75e29ab7"

id: "31"

_mt: "1"

ttl: "2419200"

_sid: "SFMC"

from: "751521060866"

alert: "Feb 07 V002"

sound: "default"

title: "Feb 07 V002"

sent_time: "1581051995078"

show_notification: "false"

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on using Firebase's messaging in conjunction with the Marketing Cloud SDK then you're going to have to configure your project for Multiple Push Providers (ref. [Multiple Push Providers Setup](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html)).

If multiple push providers wasn't your intention then please follow the plugin implementation instructions, which do not require you to add the dependency you're adding. (ref. [Cordova Plugin Installation](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin#installation))

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the recommendation. Since our App is developed using Cordova, we will have to use the library [Cordova Plugin Installation](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin#installation) for marketing cloud integration. Currently, the App include FIrebase plug in for tracking Google Analytics data so its conflicting with the Cordova Marketing Cloud SDK

Comment: You can use Firebase Analytics without including Firebase Messaging.